# Versioning policy of homebrew formula?

Tags: versioning, homebrew

I provide formula for install font, https://github.com/sanemat/homebrew-font/blob/master/ricty.rb, and I added `version '3.2.1'` same as font version.

But I want to update formula, for additional feature, so I'm confused should I bump version to `version '3.2.1.1'` ? I want to detect formula update and version up, but actual font version still `3.2.1`!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't support this (yet), what other packaging systems might call a revision.  Either you create a fake version number, as you propose, but that isn't recommended for public packages.  Or you manually uninstall and reinstall the package.